# AngluarJS DatePicker CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am using this datepicker lib https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker for my project, In my project I am trying to put the datepicker visible to the user and under that I put some text. But I have an error the datepicker hides my text.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="fecha_input margen_top2" id="id_datepicker_text">
        <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" datepicker-show="true" datepicker-append-to="id_datepicker_text">
          <input ng-model="data.fecha_actual" type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="todas_citas_func()"/>
        </datepicker>
      </div>
      This is some text to show some data | here is hidden :(
    </div>
    <div class="col s6">
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the documentation says that I should use this properties

> datepicker-show="true" datepicker-append-to="id_datepicker_text"

But I do not know what is my error
What do I want? I want my some text appears under the datepicker

Comment: I've edited your title to remove the all caps, as it is considered yelling in many corners of the internet. You mention an error, but never tell us the error. If you read [ask], that's pretty much required for us to help you understand and fix the error.

Comment: It can be a z-index issue,  try giving a higher z-index(higher than date picker)to the text you want to show. else  check the overlapping of content by inspecting it should be a simple css fix.l

Comment: I was trying with z-index but no work :( what is your idea?